# How to set up JS 'onbeforeunload()' in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I know how to use JavaScript ['onbeforeunload'](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload) for a standard HTML file. However, in Flask, we usually have the `<body></body>` tag in the `base.html`. I want to execute an `'onbeforeunload'` from just one of the pages that extends `base.html`. Setting it in the `base.html` will trigger it from all the files that extend base. How can I set it up for just one of the HTML files?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the `onbeforeunload` directly on the body tag, you can define it in the JavaScript code.

Then you'd use a `block` from Jinja to set it up only on the pages you want. Here's an example with `base.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
  
</body>
</html>
```

And then in your children you could do this:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<!-- your HTML content here... -->

<script type="application/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always be shown
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

The JavaScript code is taken from the MDN, but you can change it to suit your needs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#example

If setting the JavaScript code inside the `content` block is inconvenient (e.g. because you're already using it for other things), you could create another block with a different name toward the end of the `body` tag.